# What is Neato laser scanner rotation speed

Tags: ros, neato, xv-11-laser-driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

We have a Neato laser scanner which we are interfacing to the xv-11 laser node.  But, our scanner is rotating quite slowly, about 2 hz (120 rpm), on 3.0 volts dc.  Conflicting web data says it should be rotating at 5 or 10 hz.  Could someone tell me the speed of a properly operating unit?  Has anyone had to use voltages significantly higher than 3.0 vdc?

Thanks,
Alex

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9690/what-is-neato-laser-scanner-rotation-speed/) by [Alex Brown](https://answers.ros.org/users/125/alex-brown/) on ROS Answers with karma: 176 on 2011-04-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-04-12**:
Is that the output rate of the laser (according to say, `rostopic hz /scan`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While the original IEEE ICRA paper says 10hz, every production model I have seen is only 5 Hz.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-04-12**:
Yup... ours was 5Hz as well.